# How to fetch a value from JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array and I want to get the value of last name from it.
Can anyone tell how to get that from this array example:

```
var result = [{"FirstName":"paapu","LastName":"gandhi"}];
```

Comment: Just write `result[0].LastName`

Answer (score 1):

You have an array containing an object, so you have to retrieve the object by doing:

```
var myObj = result[0]
```

And then get the LastName property by:

```
var lastname = myObj.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the first object.

```
var obj = result[0];
```

Refer to the property of the object:

```
var prop = result[0].FirstName;
```

If property name comes dynamically, that is, from a variable, use square bracket notation.

```
var myVar = "FirstName";
var prop = result[0][myVar];
```